# How do I get to Valsad when online tickets only take me to Surat?

Tags: tickets, india, indian-railways

I want to travel from Mahesana to Valsad by train #16209 on 02/09/2016. On the Indian Railways web site, ticket availability is only up to Surat, which I booked. What do I have to do to journey further to Valsad, a short distance from Surat? Can I purchase an additional ticket from the train conductor, without penalty? If not, do I disembark at Surat and purchase a ticket in the station there?

Comment: You were shouting, using all caps and little punctuation; the changes were to make it easier to read. If I have changed your meaning, you can undo the edits.

Comment: @Gayot Fow: Lovely, coming from you; editing is definitely in my wheelhouse, as a former book publisher.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the train you have booked doesn't go to Valsad. Surat to Valsad is approximate an hour train ride and trains are [available frequently](http://erail.in/?T=ST::BL).

You can either pre-book your Surat to Valsad ticket on [IRCTC](https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf) or get general ticket from Surat station upon arrival. It won't be very difficult to get ticket from Surat station, however to be on safe side better pre-book the ticket online.